# Copying folders from file except subfolders from file

Tags: bash, rsync, copying

I want to copy some directories and files. I have made list of them (absolute path), but some of them contains folders I don't want (exclude folders also having absolute path). I want to copy only include and deeper (without files/folders mentioned in exclude) but this, and other versions I made does not seem to be running well.

```
rsync -rz  --exclude-from="$exclude" --include-from="$include" . $repository_path
```

[image]

Let say thats the file sturcture

file include has two rows:

```
/a
/b
```

file exclude:

```
/a/aa
```

And desired output:

[image]

Comment: Would you be so kind and add example file structure and expected result?

Comment: I think its much better now. If you have any more doubts @DevilaN i'll try to make it clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's drill it out with your file structure.
First of all we create testsync directory to play within:

```
mkdir testsync && cd testsync
mkdir -p a/aa/whatever b/bb c/whatever c/noneed
touch a/file.txt a/picture.jpg b/bb/morefiles.txt b/txt.txt
```

Lets check it out with `tree`:

```
.
├── a
│   ├── aa
│   │   └── whatever
│   ├── file.txt
│   └── picture.jpg
├── b
│   ├── bb
│   │   └── morefiles.txt
│   └── txt.txt
└── c
    ├── noneed
    └── whatever
```

We create `include.dat` file with contents:

```
- /a/aa/*
+ /
+ /a
+ /a/***
+ /b
+ /b/***
- *
```

More about syntax of include/exclude file in manual (`man rsync`) in section `INCLUDE/EXCLUDE PATTERN RULES`.

You HAVE TO include each directory with it's ancestor so it could be synced. That is why `/` and `/a` with `/a/***` (triple asterisk for all directory contents within) is included

We create another directory outside of testsync: `targetsync` and test:

```
rsync -az --include-from=include.dat ~/testsync/ ~/targetsync/
```

Now when we go to `targetsync` directory and use `tree` to get the picture:

```
.
├── a
│   ├── aa
│   ├── file.txt
│   └── picture.jpg
└── b
    ├── bb
    │   └── morefiles.txt
    └── txt.txt
```

Comment: Thats nice, but what if I have loads of files in various locations, and I canot litteraly exclude all directories I do not like as you did with /c

Comment: I want only files and directories listed in "include" and all their subfolders and files untill end or folder is in "exclude" its subfolders should not be copied.

Comment: @Nav: I've Changed my answer according to your suggestion.

Comment: That seems a bit weird for me. If we make a files within test folder, then the absolute path for the file a is not /a but (...)/targetsync/a and the + and - marks are suppose to be in include file? I could not find any info about that syntax, I could not reproduce your result :/

Comment: @Nav paths are for rsync relative to source directory. I've tried step by step once again with my answer and my result is reproducible. Yes, `+` and `-` means strictly include path and exclude path. It has to be done this way. What exactly do you have problem with?

Comment: I was just confused with include.dat file. It works fine. thanks